# Have simple wordpress jquery script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ok so i have a simple jquery script im trying to load into wordpress i have other scripts already working but for some reason this one is not working. I have it working just on a simple html page but right when i put in wordpress.
Could someone help me and let me know why i keep getting unknown syntax error

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery(".comb-7").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.background-hover').toggle();
    }
});
```

thanks for any help

Comment: you're passing $ as a reference, might as well use it

Comment: Any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

This cant Work, you're missing the cloosing the bracket for the hover method

Answer (score 0):

You don't close the hover method. Should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".comb-7").hover(
        function () { $(this).find('.background-hover').toggle(); });
});
```

Comment: Thank you i knew it was something easy but just needed someone else to look over and figure it out after staring at it not working for an hour i was going nuts